# Validação com Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, validação, spring-mvc

Fala galera beleza? Bom, comecei a estudar `Spring` pelos cursos da Algaworks recentemente e hoje me deparei com um problema, é o seguinte:

Tenho um formulário que me mostra uma lista de funcionários, e como foi passado no curso, também tenho um formulário para cadastro e edição que são iguais. Dai pensei em fazer um modal que serviria de formulário de cadastro e edição, então busquei como fazer isso e acabei encontrando, o modal está funcionando 90%, as validações estão sendo feitas em `JQuery`, ta cadastrando, mostrando mensagem de sucesso e tudo, mas, ai vem o problema.

Não sei se vocês sabem dessa forma de fazer validações do servidor com `Spring`, o curso nos ensinou a fazer assim:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/novo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String salva(@Validated Funcionario funcionario, Errors errors, RedirectAttributes attributes){      
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        return "redirect:/saboia/funcionarios";
    }else{          
        funcionarios.save(funcionario);         
        attributes.addFlashAttribute("mensagem","Funcionario Salvo com Sucesso!");          
        return "redirect:/saboia/funcionarios";
    }
}
```

Ou seja, se o formulário tiver erros como está sendo mostrado ali no primeiro if, então eu daria um redirect para o controlador especificado, porém, o redirect encerraria a requisição de cadastro, de forma que todos os dados seriam perdidos.

Como o formulário de cadastro não é mais uma página especifica como era antes para que eu pudesse dar um redirect então fiquei meio perdido, Como fazer as valições realizadas no servidor chegarem até meu modal?

[image: Imagem do modal]

Comment: Sugiro perguntar no próprio fórum da Algaworks. Se conseguir a resposta, você mesmo pode colocar aqui.

Comment: neste caso você precisaria devolver a resposta em formato JSON, e fazer uma chamada AJAX com o jQuery, dessa forma consegueria receber as mensagens de erro, caso ocorra e exibir na tela para o usuário.